# Multiply two matrices using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two matrices using threads in Java. I don't know what's happening with my code, because it doesn't show the product of matrices, instead it shows 0 or the memory position for my MatrixC. Here's my thread-multiplication code:

```
public class ThreadMatrix extends Thread {
    int ini, end, counter;

    // Interval for each thread
    public ThreadMatrizes(int ini, int end) {
        this.init = ini; // Position of the matrix where the thread starts
        this.end = end; // Position of the matrix where the thread ends
    }

    public void run(){

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        for (i = init; i < end; i++){
            for (j= init; j < end; j++){
                for (k = init; k < end; k++){
                    MatrixMultiplication.matrixC[i][j] += MatrixMultiplication.matrixA[i][k]*MatrixMultiplication.matrixB[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(MatrixMultiplication.matrixC[i][j]);
    }
}
```

In `System.out.prinln(MatrixMultiplication.matrixC[i][j]);` I tried to run without `[i][j]`, and the output is a memory position. What should I do?

Comment: An array doesn't have an overriden `toString()` method. Use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: Are you aware that you printing a `single` element of matrix, since you do it outside of all loops?

Answer (score 0):

To print a multi dimensional array you can use [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). This method was designed for printing multidimensional arrays.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(MatrixMultiplication.matrixC));
```

Or if you want a more customized print output you can write your own loop for example

```
for (i = init; i < end; i++){
  for (j= init; j < end; j++){
       System.out.print(MatrixMultiplication.matrixC[i][j] + " ");
  }
    System.out.println();
}
```